# Autoscroll to bottom on custom dynamic listview

Tags: android, listview

I followed example as http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dynamic-listview/

However I bump into problem applying autoscroll to bottom as

```
listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_DISABLED);
```

Where should I apply it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it was solve with adding the following line under xml file.

```
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Comment: `listview.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);` will also work.